# Laravel, add different html attributes to the options in select drop-down Lists

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel

Is there a way to add HTML attributes to an option in a dropdown select with blade `Form::select()`?

Well, because I need something like this: (add different CSS classes to the `option` tags)

```
<select id="colors" name="colors">
  <option value="1" class="blue">blue</option>
  <option value="2" class="red">red</option>
  <option value="3" class="yellow">yellow</option>
</select>
```

**UPDATE** (The CSS class name should not be the same as the text name. The css classes comes from a table in the database.)

```
<select id="colors" name="colors">
  <option value="1" class="blue">colors-blue</option>
  <option value="2" class="red">something-red</option>
  <option value="3" class="yellow">banana is yellow</option>
</select>
```

If it was just one CSS class to add to all those options, I could simply do that with jQuery. But I need to add more than one.

PS: I have the classes name stored in an table from the database.

From the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#drop-down-lists), I can't see no light. I've looked to the API also.

**Update 2** (Giving some more details of the code)

```
// In my create view I have this:
{{ Form::select( 'colored_stuffs', $colorsList, null, ['id'=>'colored_stuffs'] ) }}

// The $colorsList generate an array in the ColorsController@create
public function getCreate()
  {
    $colorsList      = $this->colors->listAll();
  }

// listAll() is defined here is this repository
public function listAll()
  {
      $colors = $this->model->lists('name', 'id', 'color_class');

      return $colors;
  }

// the HTML optput of the create view it's this
<select id="colored_stuffs" name="colored_stuffs">
  <option value="1">Red is used to alert something</option>
  <option value="2">A banana is yellow</option>
  <option value="3">Sorry no color here</option>
</select>

// But I want this
<select id="colored_stuffs" name="colored_stuffs">
  <option value="1" class="red">Red is used to alert something</option>
  <option value="2" class="light-yellow">A banana is yellow</option>
  <option value="3" class="black">Sorry no color here</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The `Form::select()` method in Laravel will not do what you're after, but it's possibly to extend the `Form` class to add the functionality you're after. The question is, are you using Laravel 4 or 5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default `Form::select()` helper will does not support what you're requesting, but you can add additional Form helpers using a [Macro](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#custom-macros):

```
Form::macro('fancySelect', function($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())
{
    $selected = $this->getValueAttribute($name, $selected);

    $options['id'] = $this->getIdAttribute($name, $options);

    if ( ! isset($options['name'])) $options['name'] = $name;

    $html = array();

    foreach ($list as $list_el)
    {
        $selectedAttribute = $this->getSelectedValue($list_el['value'], $selected);
        $option_attr = array('value' => e($list_el['value']), 'selected' => $selectedAttribute, 'class' => $list_el['class']);
        $html[] = '<option'.$this->html->attributes($option_attr).'>'.e($list_el['display']).'</option>';
    }

    $options = $this->html->attributes($options);

    $list = implode('', $html);

    return "<select{$options}>{$list}</select>";
});
```

You can use this new method with the additional `class` as required:

```
$options = [
    [
        'value' => 'value-1',
        'display' => 'display-1',
        'class' => 'class-1'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'value-2',
        'display' => 'display-2',
        'class' => 'class-2'
    ],
    [
        'value' => 'value-3',
        'display' => 'display-3',
        'class' => 'class-3'
    ],
];
echo Form::fancySelect('fancy-select', $options);
```

Comment: I've updated the question to give more details... But, yes, this is close to what I need. I'll try to implement it, but at the first view it seems to be a nice solution. Thank you

Comment: I've tested it with Laravel 5 (which does not include the `HTML` helper class by default, but can easily be added via composer.json. It should work with Laravel 4.x without any issues. You just need to save the `Form::macro() { ... }` somewhere so it's accessible to the rest of your site. Most of that code has been taken directly from the default `Form::select()` method so you shouldn't have any problems with it.

Comment: Where should I put this macro? I tried in app provider and a simple helper php with no luck.

Comment: @Moha It depends; which version of Laravel you're using?

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 3):

Creating macro is no longer necessary. From LaravelCollective 5.4 you can use 5th argument with individual attributes for all options.

```
{{ Form::select('name', $list, null, ['id' => 'colored_stuffs'],
[1 => ['color' => 'blue'], 2 => ['color' => 'red'], 3 => ['color' => 'yellow']) }}
```

You can use it to add custom data-* attributes or standard properties like disabled too.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the option and then use their text to add as class:

```
$('#colors option').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: Yes, but. Sorry (I need to edit my question). I've tryed that. and it wordked fine. But I I forgot to say that the html is sould not be the same of the class. Sorry, I will update the question.

Comment: in that case you need to add the class when you are creating option element. how are you creating them??

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do (add the class when you are creating option element). But I can't see how to include that DB field ($color) in that select option, based in laravel Form::select();

Comment: Ok, I will. Allow me a moment to update the question. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
$colors = array("green","blue","red");
echo '<select id="colors" name="colors">';
foreach($colors as $key => $color)
{
  echo '<option value="'.$key+1.'" class="'.$color.'">'.$color.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

**Update**

```
$('#colors option').each(function(){
  color = $(this).text().split("-")[1];
  $(this).addClass(color);
});
```

```js
$('#colors option').each(function(){
  color = $(this).text().split("-")[1];
  $(this).addClass(color);
});
```

```css
.blue{
  color:blue;
  }

.yellow{
  color:yellow;
  }

.red{
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="colors" name="colors">
  <option value="1">colors-blue</option>
  <option value="2">something-red</option>
  <option value="3">banana-yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I've updated the question. The css class name sould not be the same as the text name. The css classes comes from a table in the database.

Comment: I'll +1, for the answer, but the thing is that the css classes is stored dynamically in the Database, I need to get them from the dadabase, and those data (css classes in DB) could be very different from the text in the option

Comment: Any format, JSON, maybe... something like {"colored": {
  "id": "1", "color": "red"}}. Could be that...

Comment: Could be... But, I'd prefer a native laravel/php solution.

Comment: I'm stuck in how to get that JSON and provide it to the option in the list...or include the DB field(for ex: colored) in the laravel Form::select() method.

Comment: Sorry! I dont know `laravel`.

Comment: No problem. Thank you for availability in help.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, just make sure to use class as the fourth parameter

```
$yourArray = array();
```

Use

```
{{Form::select('cat_id', $yourArray,'',['class' => 'form-control'])}}
```