# How to use style in Laravel Blade form in select option

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-form

I want to have a form like this:

```html
<form>
  <select name="color">
    <option style="background: red">RED</option>
    <option style="background: green">GREEN</option>
    <option style="background: blue">BLUE</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

How can I do this with Laravel Blade?

Comment: by default laravel does not allow us to do this, you can check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28673406/5019802). it will help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel, add different html attributes to the options in select drop-down Lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672267/laravel-add-different-html-attributes-to-the-options-in-select-drop-down-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're asking about how to build select list with Laravel Collective `Form::` and add custom class to each option.

In this case, I would recommend you to create [custom macro](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#drop-down-lists).

> It's easy to define your own custom Form class helpers called "macros". Here's how it works. First, simply register the macro with a given name and a Closure

```
Form::macro('customCssSelect', function()
{
    return '<select>your HTML and PHP here</select>';
});
```

And then use it to build dropdown list:

```
Form::customCssSelect();
```

Comment: thnaks @Alexey Mezenin

Comment: Where shall I put this macro definition in Laravel 5.4 ?

Comment: @Moha in Laravel 5+ you need to install Laravel Collective package to use `Form` facade. Define macros in service provider.

Comment: Yes, I installed the collective pacgage and the standard Form facade is working. I also added a new serviceprovider, loaded it in the config/app.php, and added the macro in the register function like this:

Form::macro('colorSelect', function ($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())

However, I still always get Method colorSelect does not exist. errors when I try to use Form::colorSelect in a blade template...

Comment: @Moha did you add it to the `boot()` method?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to install [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.3/html#text) package through Composer. than you can use like this:

```
{{ 
   Form::select('color', ['red' => 'RED', 'green' => 'GREEN', 'blue' => 'BLUE'], null, ['class' => 'form-control']);
}}
```