# How to create a dropdown with colored <option> elements in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, laravel, macros

I want to create a dropdown list in Laravel 5.4 that has different background color for each `<option>` element.

I've read and tried the following:

- [How to Load Form Macros in Laravel 5](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-load-form-macros-in-laravel-5)
- [Laravel, add different html attributes to the options in select drop-down Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28672267/laravel-add-different-html-attributes-to-the-options-in-select-drop-down-lists/28673406#28673406)

None of them worked for me. I always get a **Method colorSelect does not exist.** error.

If I just want to use `Form::macro` it says that the method does not exist. I found several articles about creating your own macros, but none of them told *where* should these macros be added.

Comment: Do you want to give every option another color?

Answer (score 0):

You can add Macro's using the following steps:

1. Create a new Provider, called MacroServiceProvider.
2. Add your macro in the register method.

   ```
   public function register()
   {
       FormBuilder ::macro('time', function ($name, $default, $otherparams, ...) 
       {
           ....
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register the MacroServiceProvider in the app.config-file.

   ```
   'providers' => [

   /*
    * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
    */
    \App\Providers\MacroServiceProvider::class,
   'AltThree\Bus\BusServiceProvider',
   'Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationServiceProvider',
   ```
4. Run *composer dump-autoload -o* in a command prompt opened in your project folder.
5. You can now use your macro in your view files.